# kohana 3 like statement

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-orm

I want to know that how can I use like statement in Kohana 3 in both ways using ORM and Query builder

I am currently using sql statement like:

```
select * from tablename where keyword like "abc%"
```

I want to know its Query builder alternative and ORM alternative, I have tried:

```
->where('keyword','like',DB::expr("$keyword%"))
```

but didn't work

So what is better way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
->where('keyword','like',"$keyword%")
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you have multiple keywords, such as when exploding on a space, you can just use the array as the 3rd parameter for the where method.

```
$keywords = explode(' ', $_POST['keywords']);
DB::select()->from('table')->where('keywords', 'LIKE', $keywords)->execute();
```